# No source Available when NullReferenceException using F#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, nullreferenceexception

I use VS 2010. This

```
let b =
  let a: int option = None
  a.Value
```

gives me a nice NullReferenceException in the debugger, as expected.

Now try this one:

```
type A = B
let b2 =
  let a: A option = None
  a.Value
```

I get 'No source Available' window in the debugger instead. Why? And how to make it work correctly?

Comment: They both work correctly (i.e. both give `NullReferenceException`) on my machine using VS 2010.

Comment: using `B=int` works fine for me

Comment: pad: That is strange. So there is probably some weird setup on my machine. You do not probably know what to change to make it work, right?

Comment: @OldrichSvec Probably not important but double check your _exact_ version of VS2010.  Pad may have service pack and you might not.